# How to get metrics at Ad level using the Criteo API?

Tags: criteo

I'm using the Marketing Solutions Criteo API.

I want to withdraw metrics at Ads level, but there is no endpoint for ads, and the lowest level available seems to be Adsets.

Therefore, I'm using the endpoint statistics/report in analytics to get information on Ads level, given that there is an AdId and Ad (ad name): https://developers.criteo.com/marketing-solutions/docs/campaign-statistics

The response includes a total, and rows. I expected these rows to be at Ad level, but it's not clear to me what are these rows. For example, If I receive a 115 rows response, 28 of them have as AdId an empty string, other 28 of them have -1 as AdId and a number also repeated 28 times as another AdId, then there are just a few unique values. What is the API actually returning me on rows? It doesn't seem to be Ads, then what is it?

I cannot find anything on these rows in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically -1 is used to indicate the value for unknown or the values that are not applicable, e.g if you are querying historical data for the adset which is linked to an archived creative. To get more precise information I suggest that you reach out to the Criteo account representative of your account. I agree that something like this should be documented on the public documentation pages.